# PHP - Get the text associated with a button

Tags: php, text, get

i have problem like this.

-text | button-

-text | button-
 (*and so on*)

-text | button-

== TEXTAREA ==

eg. i have 20 sets of text and its button. when I press any button, I get the text associated with the button that i pressed, and append its text to textarea.
Here all pair of text and button using same id.

this is the code :

```
<div id="part" >
<form name='form1' id='form1'>
<div id="teks"> <?php echo $text; ?></div>
<button type="button" id="pos" name="pos" value="POS" onclick="addPOS();"/>POS</button>
</form>
</div>

<div id="part" >
<form name='form1' id='form1'>
<div id="teks"> <?php echo $text; ?></div>
<button type="button" id="pos" name="pos" value="POS" onclick="addPOS();"/>POS</button>
</form>
</div>

//and so on, up to 20 part text-button

<script type="text/javascript">
  function addPOS()
  {
      document.getElementById("posbox").value+='<?php echo $text; ?>';
  }
</script>
<div id="box" >
<textarea style="width:420px" name="posbox" id="posbox" rows="4" cols="70"></textarea>
</div>
```

I just want to add text (text beside button i press) to textarea. How to doing that?

any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: yes. simply, i just want to add text (text beside button i press) to textarea.

Comment: thanks. if you can help me with the codes.

Comment: If you want to ADD text in textbox on click (not to update it on every click), and with your current html structure: http://jsbin.com/ecowin/3/edit, maybe something like this? However, ID's should be unique... P.S. To update text on every click (remove old entry), remove + from this part: value+ P.S. PHP echoes goes instead TEXT1, tEXT2, etc...

Comment: Hi @nevermind thanks for the help, i will try your help asap. thx for the codes, talkless and great support :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to work with classes instead of ids. id must be unique . So get elements by class  `document.getElementsByClassName('');` and loop through array to change their values

Change everywhere id="" to class="" and do smth like this

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) { 
  //your code elements[i].value=
}
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that using `<label>`s instead of plain `<div>`s give better usability, nice click-on-label-to-click-on-button effect, and better semantics overall.